# Where does a question about intended usage of a programming tool or feature go?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where does a question like "what's the intended usage of `<feature name>`?" should go?

To give you a quick description, a tool that gives flexibility to do something  usually translates into people using it in whatever way they found first, leading to **bad practices**.

Where do I ask for the intended way (not to be confused with "best practices" or similar as they are kind of opinion based) for a programming tool or feature to be used?

Comment: Umm.. would that not be in the '<feature name>' documentation?  User manual, example usage and the like?

Comment: Unfortunately, with this one, it gives vagues examples that lead to different interpretations, and in consequence, bad practices. I'm pretty sure we are having bad practices on it

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Then the answer to your question is going to result in different interpretations, and different people's subjective opinions on what "the correct usage" is.  You could ask the tool's author why they choose to add the feature to the tool.  Nobody else can answer the question of why they added the feature, they can only guess.

Comment: Ya, doesn't sound like you'll be doing much more than collecting vague guesses.  If the creator of a tool can't arse themselves to properly document it, why bother trying to use it in the first place?  That's a smell right there.

Comment: Hmm maybe if I say the tool, it'd be more relevant. It's Zend Framework 2, and I want to ask how are modules supposed to be used. They don't quite explain the correct way in the docs, but zend is being around for years and it's really famous, that's why I believe there should be an "intended" way to structure the code inside modules.  Does it make it different or you guys think I'd still get vague answers?